# Should I edit questions that were asked a long time ago?

Tags: discussion

I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods) that was asked a few years ago, and last active 5 months ago. I noticed its grammar could be improved, so I decided to edit it.

Should I edit questions that are this old? I couldn't find any meta posts about this, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) says to edit whenever you think it can be improved. So, I know it's not *wrong* to do it, but I'm asking *should* I even worry about it?

Comment: I would suggest not editing a question that old, that popular (many upvotes), or that are protected. I think the grammar is sufficiently well-formed as to be understood.

Comment: That's a bad edit. The whole first paragraph is useless noise and should be removed, not tweaked.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan:  Those are the most important questions to edit, considering their wide reach and their wide applicability.  A lot of people see questions like that every day.  No reason not to spruce 'em up.

Comment: [There's a badge for that.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1286/archaeologist)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: [There's a badge for doing that once (not a hundred times)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1287/excavator)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Do it.  Just *do* it.

If you *can* improve the question, feel *encouraged* to do so.  Don't let the age of the question hold you back.

That said, be sure that your edit is substantial and concise.  Make sure you clean up any noise and any unnecessary clutter in the question.  Your current edit leaves much of that noise in.

Comment: Okay. For future reference, apart from the intro paragraph, what else would be considered noise/clutter?

Comment: @CacheStaheli:  Read the question as if you were asking another colleague this problem.  Anything that you'd omit is likely noise.  Anything that doesn't sound right when spoken is likely eligible to be rephrased.

Comment: that's a good way to look at it. Thanks.